# eappto trigger undefined control sequence error when used with hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, etoolbox, hyperlink

*You can jump to the question in bold at the bottom if you want*

I want to add examples of theorem at the end of my documents (with link after theorem to acess examples) but while having the exemple written under the theorem in my code (easier to manage).

I made this code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{exemplei}

\def\exemples{}

\newcommand{\exemple}[1]{
\hypertarget{exemple\arabic{exemplei}}{\theexemplei}
    \appto\exemples{\hyperlink{exemple\arabic{exemplei}}{Back} \theexemplei #1

     }
    \stepcounter{exemplei}
}
\begin{document}

Additions
\exemple{1+1=2}

\newpage

Multiplications
\exemple{1x1=1}

\newpage

\exemples

\end{document}
```

Unfortunatly back link didn't work. I discovered it was because `\arabic{exemplei}` was returning the last value and not the current value (probably because `\appto` was executing the code when showing the variable and not when adding text to it). I found that I had to replace `\appto` by `\eappto`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{exemplei}

\def\exemples{}

\newcommand{\exemple}[1]{
\hypertarget{exemple\arabic{exemplei}}{\theexemplei}
    \eappto\exemples{\hyperlink{exemple\arabic{exemplei}}{Back} \theexemplei #1

     }
    \stepcounter{exemplei}
}
\begin{document}

Additions
\exemple{1+1=2}

\newpage

Multiplications
\exemple{1x1=1}

\newpage

\exemples

\end{document}
```

**But now this code trigger undefined control sequence error. Why ? How to fix it ?**

I also discovered that I don't have error when not having hyperlink in content I add to the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the counter values need to be expanded, `\hyperlink` should not, so you should use `\noexpand\hyperlink` as part of the `\exemple` macro:

```
\newcommand{\exemple}[1]{%
  \hypertarget{exemple\arabic{exemplei}}{\theexemplei}%
  \eappto\exemples{\noexpand\hyperlink{exemple\arabic{exemplei}}{Back}
    \theexemplei{} #1\noexpand\par}%
  \stepcounter{exemplei}%
}
```

Spurious spaces have been removed (using `%` at the line-ends) and I inserted a forced `\par` if you want to separate each element.

Comment: Since `\par` might be redefined in certain places, I'd also use `\noexpand\par`.

Comment: @egreg: True. I've updated the code.

Comment: Thanks. Surprised by how quick I get answer :D

You also answered a question I asked myself : is there a way to do a command not printing text : i have to use %;

Do you have a link explaining this about what expand means ? Because in reality I have no idea what it really means, I just think it's to make it evaluate latter, or something related to redifinition. Things I found on internet about expand seems very complicated (I don't even know what a token is :D).

Comment: @Matheod: See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764) for a reference to `%`.

Comment: @Matheod: Expansion is a tricky concept in TeX and a core part of the language. For example `\def\abcd{abcd} \def\efgh{\abcd} \def\abcd{efgh} \efgh` prints `efgh` since the value of `\abcd` was changed, even though `\efgh` was set *before* this change. Regular programming languages don't do this, since definitions are evaluated and set at the time of definition. Instead, `\def\abcd{abcd} \edef\efgh{\abcd} \def\abcd{efgh} \efgh` will print `abcd` since `\efgh` is an `e`xpanded `def`inition of `\abcd`. Expansion could be considered synonymous with evaluation.

Comment: And why expanding hyperlink was triggering an error ?

Comment: @Matheod: At the time of adding content to `\exemples`, you don't want to expand `\hyperlink` since it's not needed. It should remain as-is (as `\hyperlink`) until you use it. The reason it caused an error depends on the definition. There would be problems during expansion if the expansion includes definitions themselves.